# Do I need both TransientFaultHandling and SaveChangesWithRetries for save data into Azure Storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680905(v=pandp.50).aspx
Transient Fault Handling gives the ability to handle connection errors etc.

`SaveChangesWithRetries()` says it can also retry when fault.

I like to know, Do I need to use `TransientFaultHandling` wrap on `SaveChangesWithRetries`;

or: since they are preventing the same thing, so `SaveChangesWithRetries()` is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is very interesting.  I would not have thought that the 'Transient Fault Handing' (TFS) guide would have been used at all with the Windows Azure Storage client.  For blobs and queues (also with some table operations), there is already a default Retry policy on it.  So, if you were going to use the TFS policies in conjunction, I would definitely remove the Retry policy (using Retry.NoRetry) that is on the storage clients by default (which is a exponential backoff within 30 seec each, 4 retry policy).

All of this being said, I have found in practice that retry policies for Windows Azure storage have proved to be worse than useless (i.e. you are better off NOT using them at all).  Without specifying a very custom retry policy, they actually don't work well at all.  Note, I am talking about storage here and not SQL Azure.  Since you are using a REST based protocol, there is no stateful connection that can get 'reset' where a retry policy kinda makes sense.  Most of the errors you end up seeing (> 90% from experience) are ones that you would *never* want to retry anyway.  For instance, most failures are 403 forbidden, DNS resolution failures, 404 errors, etc.  Almost without exception, you would never want to retry those (e.g if you have bad credentials, why would you try 4 more times?).  What ends up happening in most cases, is that you are retrying an error that will *never* succeed and you waste ~2 minutes (4 retries at 30 secs each) to finally give up.  My advice is to simply disable the policy and just handle the exception.

Comment: I got lots of error like `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 70.37.127.112:443`. I use retry policy `new FixedInterval(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));`. Hope this work, will see

Comment: I see that error very rarely.  I wonder why you are seeing that so much.  If necessary you can keep the default policy for some read operations and remove it for writes and such.

Comment: I also wondering why I hit the error so much, and why I always hit on same machine, check my new question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859286/azure-table-storage-how-to-avoid-connection-error-i-tried-retry