# Azure Table Storage, How to avoid connection error (I tried retry)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I got lots of errors like `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 70.37.127.112:443`

So I add `Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling` to retry.

But still, lots of errors (even after retry)

I like to know:

1st, since Azure is a distributed service, why am I always reach 70.37.127.112 ( I access storage by simple original `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storage_account;.....,` then use `tableContext.CreateQuery<datatype>("table_name");` ). I noticed all my tables (even in different Storage account) all hit 70.37.127.112. My question, is there a way to change it?

2nd, how to eliminate the error above totally?

error details

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 70.37.127.112:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.Execute()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteAction>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first question, the Azure Fabric Controller is in charge of allocating resources. When you request a service instance (e.g. Azure Storage) it will find an available server that will be in charge of dealing with the requests. This server may be in charge of different service instances, either yours or other people's, since Azure is a shared environment.

You can use affinity groups, [as explained by Nuno Godinho](http://msmvps.com/blogs/nunogodinho/archive/2012/03/04/importance-of-affinity-groups-in-windows-azure.aspx), to have a finer degree of control on how the Fabric Controller will provision your services (e.g. in the same cluster or in different clusters).

See [Inside Windows Azure storage: what's new and under the hood deep dive](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/SAC-961T) for a explanation on the architecture.

About the second question, on eliminating the error, I noticed that the port being refused is 443. It has happened to me before that this port was being blocked by a firewall or proxy on my own network. Please check if this is the case and have it opened.

If you're sure that your traffic can reach the remote server, the next best course of action is to open a support ticket with Windows Azure's support group. In my experience, they're quick and efficient.

For that, go to [Support options for Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/) and choose Customer Support | Windows Azure.

Comment: Most requests are fine, so I believe is not firewall issue (and the deployment is on Azure, so I do not touch the firewall yet). I also use http for some table, same errors. I will submit a ticket to them, thank you for your advice.

Comment: I think you might be confusing SQL Azure's primary server and the 2 replicated backups here for what Storage servers do.  Storage services do not quite work like that (i.e. the term 'primary' is not really applicable here).  There are partition servers, partition masters, etc.  Anyhow, rather than me try to explain in comment, watch Brad:  http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/SAC-961T

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, dunnry. Of course, what's replicated 3 times is the data, not the computing server that serves the requests. I'll update the answer.

Comment: What transaction rate are you attempting?  If you slow it down, do you see the same amount of errors?  I don't think the IP address that you're hitting is relevant.  The storage service is internally load balanced.

Comment: Is very low, less then 1 per second, I cannot slow down from that. I create a thread as M$, hope get some answer there http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/b55d0126-f80b-4df2-bcb6-8b5da37c51ff